# Log4j appenders for spring DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-mvc, log4j

for one of my applications I have a problem with log4j and appenders for the spring 3.
The exact error warning message is "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.".

I read the information about configuration of spring with log4j but I don't have any success to overcome that problem. Logging through log4j is working but with that WARN message.

This is my pom configuration for log4j and spring - it's rather long configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
         <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
         <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
         <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Plus I have one more logging related - exclusion for commons-logging for spring-core and spring-context.

This is web.xml configuration:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:META-INF/properties/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is the log4j.properties configuration:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, R
log4j.appender.R.File=application.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=700KB
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.logger.mongo=DEBUG,console
```

I'm looking for more info-source where I can find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here is the solution - thanks for the responses, there was one answer that drive me to the right direction but it seems it is deleted by the author.

Solution:
1. Move the log4.properties file from src/main/resources/META-INF/properties/log4j.properties to src/main/resources/log4j.properties
2. Change log4j configuration in web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And the problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Have-you try to add this config line to log4j.properties ?

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG,console
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - yes, I added that but the WARN remains. I continue to digging...